# How to get the placement attribute of popper tooltip?

Tags: css, attributes, tooltip, popper

I am using popper.js and I want to change some css properties of other elements based on tooltip placements. when I check the html element from browser's console, I see the attribute, so I tried to use javascript first by using `document.querySelector("#popper-popup").dataset.popperPlacement;` nothing show up, then I tried with jQuery `$("#popper-popup").attr("data-popper-placement");`, same!. finally using `$("#popper-button").has("> #popper-popup[data-popper-placement^='bottom']").css("background","red");` nothing happened. when I checked the console of codepen the placement attribute does not exist...
could anyone explain this, and how can I get the placement of the tooltip. thanks
[codepen popper popup](https://codepen.io/montassar22/pen/OJxEYbV?editors=0011)

Comment: hi, have you found the solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the answer makes sense, this is a function that I used to rotate the close button according to the popper orientation:

```
     function rotateClose(){
        $(divId+" .popover[data-popper-placement^='top']").prev().css("transform","rotate(180deg)");
        $(divId+" .popover[data-popper-placement^='left']").prev().css("transform","rotate(90deg)");
        $(divId+" .popover[data-popper-placement^='right']").prev().css("transform","rotate(-90deg)");
        $(divId+" .popover[data-popper-placement^='bottom']").prev().css("transform","rotate(0deg)");
    }
```